# Does OWIN Framework support conversion of bearer token to a cookie

Tags: cookies, owin, bearer-token

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to take the Bearer token in OWIN Framework and convert it to a cookie. Is there validation for this cookie also supported in the OWIN Framework?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, then mention it on your question and tell on which step did you fail. A lot of us want to help you but please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: I was hoping to see if there was a built in support- but now I am writing the custom cookie converter/validator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a cookieAuthenticationOption with name BearerToken automatically generates this cookie for me. So, I do not have to add a new cookie generator. Here is my code for reference (if someone needs it in the future):

```
var cookieOptions_BearerToken = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "type2",
                CookieName = "BearerToken",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                Provider =
                        new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                        {
                            OnValidateIdentity = OnValidateIdentityAsync_BearerToken,
                            OnException = OnCookieException,
                            OnResponseSignIn = OnResponseSignIn,
                        },
            };

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions_BearerToken);
```